# How to reinstall gpu in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I have installed tensorflow cpu only and now I want to enable gpu feature.
system:
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
python 3.7 using anaconda
tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 1):

See the tensorflow installation guide https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow-GPU is additional package, different from Tensorflow CPU.

**You will need CUDA-compatible GPU to use tensorflow GPU!** 
Before you start, you will need to install: CUDNN, CUDA Toolkit, libcupti.

Then, using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: it run successfully and all installed..
but now When I try to use GPU with tensorflow code (with tf.device('/gpu:0') ) i get this error:

{InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation random_normal_1/RandomStandardNormal: node random_normal_1/RandomStandardNormal (defined at /home/bignrz/untitled0.py:4) was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.}